# Trigger pipeline on environment change (Resource added)

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is it possible to create a trigger on a azure pipeline that gets fired when there is a change in the associated environment?

Specifically, I would really like to be able to trigger the pipeline whenever a resource is added to the environment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is impossible to achieve this. Adding a new resource to the environment doesnot trigger an event in azure devops. See [available events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops). You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to Microsoft development team regarding this issue.

However,  As a workaround you can have a try defining a pipeline which will be triggered at certain intervals by using [scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#scheduled-trigger). And [invoke rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to check the changes to the environment in a script task in the pipeline. And then trigger your pipelines in the scheduled pipeline using [Trigger Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) task when there are changes to the environment

Comment: Done! Thank you, I have created a feedback ticket.